# How should I test my application?

Tags: testing, unit-testing, applications

I have made a simple application which searches for files and folders on users computer. Since, I am a student currently in my 1st year and don't have any formal training and have made my application while I was still learning C# and .Net framework, I didn't have knowledge about unit tests and other good testing methods used by professionals. Although, most of my code is working fine, sometimes it throws exceptions or some other unexpected situation occurs and the code breaks.

Keeping the above experiences in mind, I don't think my application is ready for deployment and so , I would like to test my application in a professional way, and be assured that my application is bug free.

Therefore, I want to ask professionals here, that keeping my situation in mind, how should I start testing my application.
What are the steps that I should follow, to ensure the quality of my application.

Comment: New to testing? Start with writing an *integration test* to ensure that your app doesn't have gigantic bugs. The test first creates a *fixture* (a known state like a fresh temp directory with contains the wanted file and some decoys). Then let your program do its work, and assert that the correct file was found. Then write another test where the the fixture does not include any matching files, and assert that no file is found. Such tests are easy when your app runs on the command line, or when it has a good internal API. Use some test framework like xUnit to run tests and report results.

Comment: For your next application, consider writing your tests *first,* or at least while you write your methods.  This will force you to think about writing your methods in such a way that they are easily testable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Lesson learnt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 0: focus, and don't get overwhelmed**

There are several types of testing you can do. There's unit testing, acceptance testing, integration testing, test driven development (TDD), behavior driven development (BDD), acceptance test driven development (ATDD) etc. Don't get bogged down in terminology just yet. Focus on acceptance testing (see note), which roughly means to test the final version of your complete program. Once you get your feet wet with the simplest possible tests, you can start to look at the bigger world of software testing.

> Note: Some folks may give advice to start with unit testing. That's
>   cool, too. That can be pretty easy if you're using a language with a
>   built-in unit testing framework. If not, installing a unit testing
>   framework can be a pain. This is why I recommend starting with
>   acceptance testing, because you don't need a fancy framework. All you need
>   is a way to call your program from a script or from another program. You
>   probably already have the tools to do that on your machine.

**Step 1: create some test data**

Create a folder, and in that folder put some dummy files. Make it so that you can easily find all of them (eg: their names all start with "f"), some of them (eg: some names end with a "Z", some don't), none of them (eg: none have the word "foobar" in their name). This is your test data. If your program can search sub-folders, create a few subfolders, too.

**Step 2: create a simple test script**

Write a test script using whatever scripting language you are comfortable with -- python, bash, powershell, etc. This script should call your program with parameters to search for files. For example, it should tell it where to search (eg: your new folder) and what to search for (eg: F*, *Z, *foobar*). Since you control how many files are in your test folder, you should know that a search for F* will return X files, searching for *Z should return Y files, and searching for *foobar* should return 0.

Note: you don't have to use a scripting language. Usually that's easier than creating a compiled test program. If you only know one language, though, use that language for now.

It really doesn't have to be any fancier than that -- a single script that calls your function, and then verifies that what it returns is what you expect. Do that for several different search criteria. Have your script print out a simple name for each test, and either "PASS" or "FAIL".

**Step 3: add more test cases**

As you're writing your first tests, you'll probably write tests for the simple cases. Think about *edge cases* -- testing the boundaries of what your code can do. Does your program accept an argument telling it where to search? Write a test where you don't give it the argument to make sure it prints an appropriate error message. Can you pass more than one argument? Arguments that are empty strings, or paths to folders that don't exist?

As you uncover bugs, add a test case *before* you fix the bug so that you can duplicate it. Fix the bug, and verify that your test case now passes. As you add new features you can do the same thing -- add a test *before* adding the new feature. It should fail, until you get that feature working. This is known as TDD, or Test Driven Development.

**Step 4: learn**

Once you're comfortable with how that works, you can start looking at other tools to make this easier. For example, [cucumber](http://cukes.info/) or the [robot framework](http://www.robotframework.org) are good choices for acceptance testing, but there are many, many others.